# A question about the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

I am trying to determine a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}})$ as a field extension over $\mathbb{Q}$, and my attempt is to choose an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}})$ then find a basis through doing the multiples of that element, and I get:

$x^0 = 1$

$x^1 = a + b \sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}}$

$x^2 = (a^2 + 3b^2) + 2b^2 \sqrt{2} + 2ab \sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}}$

$\cdots$

But through this way I don't know whether this process will end by getting a set which is multiplicatively closed or not. So can someone tell me what the right way to do this problem is, or give me some hint on my way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the basis." There are many different bases. In general taking powers of a single element might give you a basis, but only if the element generates the field as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Note for example that $\sqrt{2}$ is in your field, but its powers won't give you a basis. So if you just need a basis, try taking powers of $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{2}}$ until you find a linear dependence

Comment: By basis, I mean the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+ \sqrt{2}})$ as a vector field.

Comment: The problem with the phrasing is that there are many bases for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}})$, so one would not use the word "the" to identify a basis.

Comment: I found that $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{2}} $ have to be in the basis of the field extension, but I don't know how to determine other elements in the basis.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/700845/1251882) should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}$ **have to** be in the basis. Bases are fairly arbitrary, only $\Bbb Q$-linear dependence is needed.

There is a canonical way to find a basis. Find a primitive element... well, that's easy - take $\alpha=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}$. Find the degree of the minimal polynomial. "Clearly" it should be four; explicitly, $(\alpha^2-3)^2-2=0$ and $x^4-6x^2+7$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, e.g. reduce modulo $2$. Then $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ is a basis!

Comment: Thanks very much! I now understand how to do it!